# Data conversion from accelerometer

Tags: c, embedded, accelerometer

Hi all I am working on an accelerometer bma220 , and its datasheet says that data is in 2's complement form.So what i had to do was getting that 8 bit data in any 8 bit signed char and done.
the bma220 have an 8 bit register of which first 6 bits are data and last two are zero.

```
void properdata(int16_t *msgData)
{
    printf("\nin proper data\n");
    int16_t temp, i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        temp = *(msgData + i);
        printf("temp = %d sense = %d\n", temp, sense);
        temp = temp >> 2;    // only 6 bits data
        temp = temp / sense; //decimal value * .0625 = value in g
        printf("temp = %d\n", temp);            
    }    
}
```

in this program i am taking data in a unsigned variable msgdata and doing all the calculations on a signed variable. I just need to know if this is the correct way to convert data?

---

After some suggestions i changed my code to this

```
  void properdata(uint16_t *msgData)
  {
    int arr[3];
    arr[0] = msgData[0];
    arr[1] = msgData[1];
    arr[2] = msgData[2];
    arr[0] = arr[0]/4;
    arr[1] = arr[1]/4;
    arr[2] = arr[2]/4;
    printf("x = %d y = %d z = %d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
 }
```

now in a stand still condition i am getting data as 61, 60 and 17.If I think data should be in a range 31 to -32 but here it is coming out of range?

Answer (score 2):

> in this program i am taking data in a unsigned variable msgdata

No you aren't. msgdata is a signed variable.

> I just need to know if this is the correct way to convert data?

Using bit-wise operators on signed variables is almost always a bug. You perform a right shift on a signed variable, this is implementation-defined behavior and what will happen to the sign bit depends on the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems in your code:

1) As Lundin stated out, shifting negative values to the right is dangerous since behavior is compiler specific.

2) According to the data sheet the range of the accelerator is 1.94 ...- 2.00 g. You try to store the value as plain integer. At least fix point arithmetic is needed here (or float). Or your result will just be  1, 0 , -1 or -2.

The following code should take these points into account (not tested):

```
int16_t  raw;       // the 8 bit raw value from the chip
int32_t  accel;     // acceleration in mg

raw =  (int16_t) read_value_from_chip();   // get 8 bits raw value from chip

accel = (int32_t)(raw / 4) * 625;  // to avoid to shift to right, use division here
if ( accel >= 0 )
  accel = ( accel + 5 ) / 10;
else
  accel = ( accel - 5 ) / 10;

printf("%ld\n", accel);
```

Explanation:

According to the data sheet the resolution is 62.5 mg and the most significant 6 bits hold the signed raw value.

To avoid to deal with the sign explicitly when bringing the bits into position the division is used here instead of the right-shift. Dividing by 4 is used instead of >> 2. This keeps the sign as required.

An optimizing compiler will replace this division by a bit-shift if the compiler/MCU sets bits on the left side 1 when negative values are shifted to the right. If the compiler/MCU does not support this, the division will be used.

*625 is done to get the acceleration in the required resolution of 1/10 mg (1 digit is 0.1 mg). 625 is the short form of 0.0625 * 10000. (**Updated**)

To get it in mg the acceleration is divided by 10 (I do this here just since mg is handier than 0.1 mg). To round correctly the half of the dividend must be added/subtracted according to the sign before dividing, here this is 10/2 = 5.

The result is now in mg.

If you want to avoid the division, you must handle negative/positive values explicitly when bringing the significant bits into place.

Comment: i am focusing on getting data in a range 31 to +32. if that is fulfilled converting to g value is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the spec sheet will have an example conversion or two.  It might show the value 0000 0000 (binary) is zero, and 0100 0000 is 47.25 g.  Run the example values through your code to validate.

Comment: No conversion example in datasheet. It says that acceleration data is in 2's complement .It gives a table as how those decimal values are to be interpreted in g as -32 is equal to -2.0g

Comment: @mrigendra:  The table does indeed contain the test and verification values.